# How to set input text value from table data on click of that row in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a jsp page where i am displaying value from data base .
Now i need to edit the table value in click of that particular row and that selected row value should get set into respective input text .

My java script function is getting called but clicked value is not getting displayed into respective input type .

The java script function name is `onRowClick`

I am adding code for that .
Please suggest .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script>
                    function onRowClick(){
                var table = document.getElementById("hoteltable"),rIndex;

                for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                    {
                         rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                         document.getElementByName("hId").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementByName("hName").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementByName("hArea").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementByName("hNumOfRooms").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementByName("hImgUrl").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;                 
                         hideButton();
                         showDelete();
                         showEdit();
                    };
                }
                    }


         </script> 
</head>
<body>
       <h2>Welcome to Admin Page</h2>
       <div id="sub-left">
             <form:form action="hotelaction" method="post" modelAttribute="hotel">
                    <table>
                           <tr>
                                 <td>hotelId</td>
                                 <td><form:input name="hId" path="hotelId"></form:input></td>
                                 <td><form:errors path="hotelId" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>

                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                                 <td>hotelName:</td>
                                 <td><form:input name="hName" path="hotelName"></form:input></td>
                                 <td><form:errors path="hotelName" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>

                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                                 <td>hotelArea:</td>
                                 <td><form:select name="hArea" path="hotelArea">
                                               <form:option value="Marthalli">Marathalli</form:option>
                                               <form:option value="SilkBoard">SilkBoard</form:option>
                                        </form:select></td>
                                 <td><form:errors path="hotelArea" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>

                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                                 <td>hotelNumberOfRooms:</td>
                                 <td><form:input name="hNumOfRooms" path="hotelNumOfRooms"></form:input></td>
                                 <td><form:errors path="hotelNumOfRooms" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                                 <td>hotelImgUrl:</td>
                                 <td><form:input name="hImgUrl" path="hotelImgUrl"></form:input></td>
                                 <td><form:errors path="hotelImgUrl" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>

                           </tr>

                    </table>



                           <div id="sub-right">

             <input type="submit" value="Add" name="action" id="btn1" class="glass2"></input> <br> <br> 
             <input type="submit"value="Edit" name="action" id="btn2"  class="glass2" /><br> <br>
             <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action" id="btn3" class="glass2"></input><br> <br>
             <input type="reset"value="Reset" name="reset" onClick=showButton(); class="glass2" />
       </div>

             </form:form>
       </div>



       <div class="myTable">
             <table id="hoteltable" border="1" width=100%>
                    <tr>
                           <td><h4>hotelId</h4></td>
                           <td><h4>hotelName</h4></td>
                           <td><h4>hotelArea</h4></td>
                           <td><h4>hotelNumOfRooms</h4></td>
                           <td><h4>hotelImageUrl</h4></td>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach var="hotels" items="${hotelList}">
                           <tr onclick="onRowClick()">
                                 <td >${hotels.hotelId}</td>
                                 <td>${hotels.hotelName}</td>
                                 <td>${hotels.hotelArea}</td>
                                 <td>${hotels.hotelNumOfRooms}</td>
                                 <td>${hotels.hotelImgUrl}</td>
                           </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
             </table>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you don't edit answers into the question.

Comment: For your next question, when the question is just about the client-side part, please include the HTML that gets sent to the browser, not the JSP source code that creates that HTML. That way, we know exactly what the client-side DOM looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the web console, you'll find an error message. There is no `document.getElementByName` function in the DOM. There's [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) (plural), but not a singular, and that one wouldn't really help you since it would give you a collection of all of the elements with that name, anywhere on the page. (Although if the only ones with those names are the ones you want, you could use it and then use `[0]` to get the only entry in the resulting collection.)

There's a different problem, though: Your `click="onRowClick()"` doesn't pass on any information about which row was clicked, and the function itself just hooks up event handlers on the rows rather than actually doing what you want done on click.

Instead, hook `click` on the table, and check to see if the click passed throug a row; if it did, fill in the information in the first table. See comments:

```js
// Hook click on the table, rather than individual rows
document.getElementById("hoteltable").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Make sure the click passed through a row in this table
    var row = e.target.closest("tr");
    if (!row || !this.contains(row)) {
        return;
    }
 // Get the form we're filling in
 var form = document.querySelector("form[action=hotelaction]");
 // Fill in the various inputs
 // Note: I'd recommend giving each cell a data-name attribute or something
 // and using those rather than using `row.cells[0]` and such. That way
 // when (not if ;-) ) you change the source table, the cell references
 // aren't messed up
    form.querySelector("[name=hId]").value = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
    form.querySelector("[name=hName]").value = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
    form.querySelector("[name=hArea]").value = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
    form.querySelector("[name=hNumOfRooms]").value = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
    form.querySelector("[name=hImgUrl]").value = row.cells[4].innerHTML;                 
    /*
    hideButton();
    showDelete();
    showEdit();
    */
});
```

```html
<h2>Welcome to Admin Page</h2>
<div id="sub-left">
  <form action="hotelaction" method="post" modelAttribute="hotel">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>hotelId</td>
        <td>
          <input name="hId" path="hotelId">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="error"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hotelName:</td>
        <td>
          <input name="hName" path="hotelName">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="error"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hotelArea:</td>
        <td>
          <select name="hArea" path="hotelArea">
            <option value="Marthalli">Marathalli</option>
            <option value="SilkBoard">SilkBoard</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="error"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hotelNumberOfRooms:</td>
        <td>
          <input name="hNumOfRooms" path="hotelNumOfRooms">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="error"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hotelImgUrl:</td>
        <td>
          <input name="hImgUrl" path="hotelImgUrl">
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="error"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="sub-right">
      <input type="submit" value="Add" name="action" id="btn1" class="glass2"><br> <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="action" id="btn2" class="glass2" /><br> <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action" id="btn3" class="glass2"><br> <br>
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" onClick=showButton(); class="glass2" />
    </div>

  </form>
</div>

<div class="myTable">
  <table id="hoteltable" border="1" width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h4>hotelId</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4>hotelName</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4>hotelArea</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4>hotelNumOfRooms</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4>hotelImageUrl</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Savoy</td>
      <td>Marthalli</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Savoy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Marriott</td>
      <td>SilkBoard</td>
      <td>450</td>
      <td>https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Marriott</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Premier Inn</td>
      <td>Marthalli</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Premier+Inn</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note that I removed from JSP- or template-isms from the HTML in that, so it used standard form inputs. I assume what gets delivered to the browser uses standard form elements.

Comment: @AtharvThakur - I'd misunderstood your structure. I've updated and provded a runnable example.